# Creating a function to edit a list with a variable number and given string

Tags: javascript, list, function, loops

I am trying to create a function that takes two parameters, a number and a string.  I need to be able to call it with a number, n, so that the nth element of theList will be modified to read as the string from the function.
I am a BEGINNER, so I am struggling with this -- I know that what I currently have in the function is NOT what I need, but I was hoping to use it as a starting point that I could adapt.  I am thinking I probably need to use looping to do this...beyond that, I dont have many ideas.  Any guidance?

```
<html>

<script>

function doit() {
document.getElementById('element1').innerHTML='Element one';
document.getElementById('element2').innerHTML='Element two';
document.getElementById('element3').innerHTML='Element three';
}
</script>
<body>
<p>Value: <input type="text" id="theInput" value="" size=10>
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="doit()"></p>
<ul id="theList">
<li id="element1">Element 1
<li id="element2">Element 2
<li id="element3">Element 3
</ul>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your li elements does not have closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to get the children (li) element of the ul tag. It will return an array of all of the children. Note, the array is zero-indexed. You will need to keep this in mind when passing index in, or update the code to -1 from the index.

```
function updateListItem(index, text) {
    var myListItem = $("#theList").children()[index]; // DOM reference to the list item

    $(myListItem).text(text); // update the text
}
```

Without jQuery, you can do it something like this:

```
function updateListItem(index, text) {
    var myListItem = document.getElementById("theList").children[index] // An array of the list items
    myListItem.innerHTML = text; // update the text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas as to what you should do:

1. For function `doit`, you need to add two parameters representing the string and the number.
2. Next, create a variable that is the concatenation (string addition) of "element" and your number parameter
3. Finally, use your above method to set `document.getElementById(<your string here>)` to whatever your string was.

Here is an example of a quick implementation:

```
function doit(str, num){
  var elementID = "element" + num;
  document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = str;
}
```